# How can I set player permissions in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'd like to have two levels of player permissions on my Bukkit server:

1. Admin: can run all commands
2. Normal: can join, chat and walk around; nothing else

How can I set this up and warn players who try to break blocks?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a permissions plugin.  Effectively you'll create two groups - one which is 'admin' and one which is 'user'.  You can look here: https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/the-ultimate-guide-to-permissions.80291/

However, it'd be easier to just set the default gamemode to Adventure and then manually promote people by changing their gamemode to Creative. You can see that here:
http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Gamemodes